# lookbehind and using it with grep in Vi?

Tags: vim, vi, regular-expression

Trying to get into Vi (not Vim), after learning Vim.

1. Vim has a lookabehind like `/\(Not this\)\@<!$`, how to do it in Vi?
2. If I want to search recurvively down directory in Vim, I could do `:vimgrep /\(Not this\)\@!$ -r *`, what about Vi?
3. if (1) and (2) are not available in Vi, how do you accomplish them?

Please, create tag `lookbehind` and `regex`.

Comment: not sure what lookbabehind is... so I'm not gonna create that tag. created regex as a tag synonym though.

Comment: xenoterracide:   'not\@<!yes' is the lookbehind, matches "yes", "yesyes" but no match with "notyes"

Answer (score 1):

According to vim help (`:help pattern-overview`), `\@i` is not supported by vi.

It may be you can enumerate all the possible combinations to avoid this, or find a different expression. Alternatively I guess you could farm the job off to some external tool or interpreter like perl. I checked egrep -- it doesn't support it. What are you searching for?

Out of interest, why are you preferring vi over vim?

Comment: read, read and read [1]. Personally, Vim is powerful but it is becoming bloated with a huge amount of properties, verbose license and edited manuals that are very hard to understand (without seeing the originals). It is easier to understand Vim and its development going some development cycles backwards. I am still total newbie but I feel mastering Vi may help to understand Vim. Step by step. [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up installing the complete version of vim in $HOME, even on Unix stations like Solaris stations, that only have the old vi at first.

Otherwise, grep+egrep+$(), or even perl as Edd suggested, will do the trick from the shell.